# Firefox Dev Edition as Default Browser

Tags: firefox, default

I manually installed Firefox Developer Edition, added it to the dock, and set it as my default browser. All was good, but now it displays a secondary gear icon in the dock when I open it by clicking a link elsewhere in the OS:
[image: screenshot of my dock after Firefox is opened through an external click.]

My default browser choice in settings also shows the gear icon. What's going on?
[image: screenshot of my Applications settings pane.]

Edit with two details to add:

1. No matter which way Firefox Dev launches, it keeps its state
   (remembering open tabs, etc.). So if it launches via an external
   click of a URL, then I quit and reopen using the dock icon, it still
   has that tab open.
2. If I already have Firefox Dev open via the dock or Applications launcher and then I click a link in another program, it opens a new
   tab in the open Firefox Dev instance and does not add that other
   icon to the dock.

Answer (score 1):

I found the same issue when setting Firefox Developer Edition as my default browser. Then when opening the default browser using a shortcut, it opens a separate dock icon.

I looked in ~/.local/share/applications and found the added shortcut. It looks like it was using `firefox-bin` as the executable.

If you change the executable in your custom shortcut to point to `firefox-bin` it should fix the issue. (it did for me)